# SharePoint 2013 Infopath Form Issue

Tags: infopath

When browse form with parameter at URL from mobile it show the following error
"infopath The form you are trying to open is not enabled for use on a mobile device"
If we browse the same URL from PC it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to render the form in mobile device:

On the Tools menu, click Form Options.

In the **Form Options** dialog box, click the **Browser category**.

To add an Update button to the toolbar of the mobile device, under Include the following commands on the toolbars, in the Toolbarssection, select the Update check box.

Under **Mobile Devices**, select the **Enable rendering on a mobile device** check box.

Click **OK** to return to the form template.

**Save** the form template to the location of your choice.

For details refer to the below MSDN article :

[Design a form template for use on a mobile device](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/design-a-form-template-for-use-on-a-mobile-device-c8afdd6d-280f-40b6-9348-28077d8d34d6)

Comment: this setting is not found at infopath 2010 or 2013 and it is found only in infopath 2007

Comment: Ohh. You can try by activating the "Mobile Browser View" feature

Comment: I already activated it but the issue still exists